# How to create a custom deeply-nested right-click menu items in dolphin?

Tags: linux, dolphin

I wish to make app (on windows and on linux with dolphin desktops) that lets users create custom-right-click menus.

Is there a way to add deeply-nested right-click sub-items? To be clear, i wish to have a custom root item, not under "Actions" or another pre-specified item, which name i cannot change.

Here is an example:
[image]

Also, do you know any other Linux desktop environments, that let me create deeply-nested right-click items?

Edit:
I found Dolphin Service Menus (https://develop.kde.org/docs/extend/dolphin/service-menus/), which looks promising, however, i cannot make it work deeper than one level.

```
[Desktop Entry]
X-KDE-Submenu=A
Type=Service
MimeType=image/*;
Actions=itemA
Icon=folder

[Desktop Action itemA]
Name=A.A
X-KDE-Submenu=A.A
Type=Service
MimeType=image/*;
Icon=folder
Exec=
Actions=itemAA

[Desktop Action itemAA]
Name=A.A.A
Icon=folder
Exec=
```

[image]